# What do I need to learn to manage a server/deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, chef-infra, unicorn

I'm a rails developer (with about a year of experience) and I am getting pretty comfortable with it, but I find that I lack even a cursory understanding of how deploys or servers work. I am familiar with terms like Unicorn or Apache, but I don't know much beyond the notion that they manage rails instances (?).

I have heard of chef, and I know it is used for deploys, but I don't know where I'd begin.

Is there a book or a screencast series that would be useful in learning this sort of thing?

(Side note: I have a project I want to make that will run sort of like a template builder and a web host, so understanding how to add domains/subdomains/manage that sort of thing is one of the primary drives for learning, other than the natural want to learn).

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with remote (or even local) deploys, I find that the best solution is using `capistrano`. You can find all the information you need at [their website](http://www.capistranorb.com/).

You can start reading the long [README](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/README.md) from Github and then switch to more detailed information starting from [here](http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/installation/).

When deploying a Rails application, usually servers like Apache or nginx acts as a router to your application's local server. Eg. you start a `thin` server for your deployed app that answers on the 1234 port and configure Apache to redirect all the calls to you remote address to the local server at localhost:1234.

Capistrano will start/restart/stop the local Rails server through the configuration you'll put in the config files, so you'll have complete control over it.

Hopes this helps. You can find lots of information online about `capistrano` and the integration with various http servers and rails servers.

Eg. a good starting point can be [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks) made by Ryan Bates, but **beware!** This is for the older 2.x version of `capistrano`.

Comment: Hi there, is working with Capistrano dependent on Ruby knowledge? I've started working in an environment where Capistrano is the chosen tool but I'm from a PHP background. Got deadline to skill up in Capistrano so was wondering if you have any recommendations on how to go about it? Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to know too much about the Ruby language to proficiently use Capistrano. You can follow the main examples and I think you'll be fine. By the way Ruby is a very natural language and really easy to learn (I too came from PHP, and I got used to it in no time).

Answer (score 1):

I have lots of things to tell regarding this. I'm on chef for around a month, and I've spent tons of hours understanding how it works. And I'd say the official docs are just a disaster. They give everything in one place, although you don't need to know it in the begging. I can only offer you some resources like: http://learnchef.getharvest.com/ which is best ever introduction I've found around. All those official learnchef links didn't work out for me.

I'd really recommend to stay away from `Vagrant` for a while, just buy a 5$ vps on DigitalOcean cloud and try this manual: http://adamcod.es/2013/06/04/deploy-a-basic-lamp-stack-digital-ocean-chef-solo.html

Start with a `chef-solo` instead of `chef-server`, and try `knife-solo`. Use `berkshelf` although it's rarely mentioned in official docs, because `chef` can't handle cookbook dependencies although it can download cookbooks. then slowly start looking how I've automatized a `chef-server` installation: http://github.com/holms/chef-starter This will give you an idea, which steps to take for `chef-server` setup, and how to deploy stuff with `knife`.

After all that, try `vagrant`, as it offers to run everything from your desktop machine. I've started from `vagrant` and I've wasted too much time. When you put `chef-server` and `vagrant` together, you get tons of information which you just unable to handle. Lots of cave heats appears, lots of things to write.. you ending up wasting your 40 hours non-stop learning, without achieving your desired results.

You can contact me on freenode irc if you need any help. I'd never wish this chef experience even to my enemy.

**Update**:
This is quite old comment :) So just ignore it. Ended up using vagrant+chef, then vagrant+ansible,  now using docker. To be exact docker+traefik

Answer (score 1):

Don't go anywhere but straight to latest awesome chef fundamental series, check opsode user on youtube (http://www.youtube.com/user/Opscode).

First episode:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yh9osPQA_-k

after it you can go to irc, docs, watch other advanced things (including berkshelf). But first things first.